# How to "disable" a bean reference in camel blueprint?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I'm using camel. This is (an extract of) my blueprint:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
    <cm:property-placeholder id="placeholder" persistent-id="com.adelco.articulos" />
    <!-- Configures the Inbound and Outbound SAP Connections -->
    <bean id="sap-configuration" class="org.fusesource.camel.component.sap.SapConnectionConfiguration">
        .
        .
    </bean>

    <!--A lot of things here, let's omit them-->
    <!-- Route beans--> 
    <bean id="rutaSTEPEntrada" class="com.adelco.articulos.RutaSTEPEntrada"/>
    <bean id="rutaSTEPSap" class="com.adelco.articulos.RutaSTEPSap"/>

    <camelContext id="camel-articulos" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <routeBuilder ref="rutaSTEPEntrada"/>   
        <routeBuilder ref="rutaSTEPSap"/>
    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

I want "disable" the bean "**sap-configuration**" but without using  XML comments. Something like this:

```
<bean id="sap-configuration" enabled=${ENABLED} class="org.fusesource.camel.component.sap.SapConnectionConfiguration">
    .
    .
</bean>
```

I can define the camel routes I want to activate using "**autoStartup**" and property placeholders "**autoStartup=${ENABLED}**" but I can't find how to do this with the bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Its how OSGi blueprint works. If you define a `<bean>` then its in use.